# I'm trying to retrieve single field set from Mongo DB, can I do that?

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch only one field details form Mongo DB, can id do that?

```
var coll = dbobj.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("getResList");
var sa = coll.FindAll().ToList();
ViewBag.dropvalue = sa;
```

This set of code will give all the details from the collection, but I want to get whole value of sigle field.

My sample Mongo data is:

```
{ 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac36369f999cb77fbf1e0dd"), 
            "campaignId" : "6QndK", 
            "href" : "https://api.getresponse.com/v3/campaigns/6QndK", 
            "name" : "deegrp", 
            "description" : null, 
            "isDefault" : "false", 
            "createdOn" : "2018-04-03T11:19:23+0000"
            }
            { 
             "_id" : ObjectId("5ad58dc84e0e4dfe295c8380"), 
             "campaignId" : "6Luex", 
             "href" : "https://api.getresponse.com/v3/campaigns/6Luex", 
             "name" : "deegrp2", 
             "description" : null, 
             "isDefault" : "false", 
             "createdOn" : "2018-04-17T06:01:33+0000"
             }
```

I want to retrieve `'campaignId'` of every person.

Comment: This is basic MongoDB functionality; it is called _projection_, and is described in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = Schema.find({}).select({'campaignId':1});

query.exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
    if(data.length>0){
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you will add a short description about the answer.